# How to properly format recursion base case to limit infinite iterations?

Tags: python, list, if-statement, recursion

RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded while calling a Python object

I am trying to add any odd numbers to 'res' and multiply any even number to 'res' while going through a list using recursion.

Input is:

```
calc_res([3, 2, 2, 4, 15], 2))
```

Output should be:
95

Assume the first element is always odd, and ignore the element if it is 0.

My code as of now is:

```
def calc_res(some_list, res):
    i = 0
    if some_list[i] >= len(some_list):
        return
    if some_list[i] % 2 != 0:
        result = i + res
        return result + calc_res(some_list, res)
    if some_list[i] % 2 == 0:
        result = i * res
        return result + calc_res(some_list, res)

print(calc_res([3, 2, 2, 4, 15], 2))
```

Comment: In the parts that trigger the recursion you don't do anything to _reduce_ the input, you just call `calc_res(some_list, res)` again? (Also, your first `return` returns `None`?)

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass your intermediate result as parameter to next recursion call.

And when no elements exists, you can just return res you passed in.

```py
def calc_res(some_list, res):
    if len(some_list) == 0:
        # no remaining elements, just return the result.
        return res

    current_number = some_list[0]
    if current_number % 2 != 0:
        # this means that calc_res from the remaining of some list.
        # and current number's result is added to res, pass to next call.
        return calc_res(some_list[1:], res + current_number)
    else:
        if current_number == 0:
            return calc_res(some_list[1:], res)
        else:
            return calc_res(some_list[1:], res * current_number)
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this may work better:

```py
def calc_res(some_list, res, i=0):
    if i == len(some_list):
        return res
    if some_list[i] % 2 != 0:
        result = some_list[i] + res
    else:
        result = some_list[i] * res
    return calc_res(some_list, result, i + 1)

print(calc_res([3, 2, 2, 4, 15], 2))
```

Here, we add a third argument to `calc_res()` which is the index `i` in `some_list` to process in a given call. If `i` has reached the end of `some_list`, we return `res`. Otherwise, we either add or multiply the `i`'th element of `some_list` and recursively call `calc_res()` with the updated result and an incremented value of `i`.

Other solutions are possible, such as avoiding `i` and instead passing smaller slices of `some_list` down the recursion stack, but an approach without slices uses less space.

Answer (score 0):

Modifying constantstranger's answer to ignore the element in some_list if its value is 0 gives:

```
def calc_res(some_list, res, i=0):
    if i == len(some_list):
        return res
    if some_list[i] % 2:
        result = some_list[i] + res
    elif some_list[i]:
        result = some_list[i] * res
    else:
        return res
    return calc_res(some_list, result, i + 1)

print(calc_res([3, 2, 2, 4, 15, 0], 2))
```

Output: `95`